# How to set value of check box dynamically in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var sites = sites_str.split(",");

$.each(sites,function(i,j) {

$('.check').append("<input type=checkbox name=site_name value=sites[i]>"+sites[i] +"</br>"

})
```

while iam trying to print selected check box values using the below code,

```
av=document.getElementsByName("site_name");


for (e = 0; e < av.length; e++)
{
    if (av[e].checked == true)
    {
       alert(av[e].value);
    }
}
```

it is giving "sites[i]" as check box value. Can some one please help?

Comment: you haven't added value properly to checkbox
you should use as like below.

$('.check').append("<input type=checkbox name=site_name value="+"sites[i]"+">"+sites[i] +"</br>"

Comment: it is giving error                                                                                 index.js:52 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: you are missing bracket ) after  </br> tag
put it as like below.
$('.check').append("<input type=checkbox name=site_name value="+"sites[i]"+">"+sites[i] +"</br>")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below piece of code. You are hardcoding the sites[i] as a string.

```
var sites = sites_str.split(",");

$.each(sites,function(i,j) {

$('.check').append("<input type=checkbox name=site_name value="+sites[i]+">"+sites[i] +"</br>")

})
```

Comment: Sry. Missed a ) at the end.